# create-react-app with typescript - how to put types in separate file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I'm using CRA with typescript (`create-react-app myapp --typescript`)

I have some typescript stuff in my `App.tsx` that I would like to store externally, and I've tried creating `App.d.ts`, `index.d.ts`, `module.d.ts` and none of it works.

Here's the interface I'm using:

```
declare interface IArgs {
    home: string,
    away: string
}
```

What do I need to do to be able to declare all my Typescript stuff in a file that my source files can share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put in external file eg. `interfaces/interfaces.ts`:

```js
export interface IArgs {
    home: string,
    away: string
}
```

Then in `App.tsx` where you want to use it you import it by: `import { IArgs } from 'interfaces/interfaces';` and use it for your needs.